# Compare associations on different ActiveRecords without fetching from the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I would like to be able to compare associated records on ActiveRecords, without actually fetching from the database. The following will do that comparison, but hits the DB when I make the comparison

```
employee1 = Employee.find_by(name: 'Alice')
  DEBUG   Employee Load (92.0ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."name" = 'Alice' LIMIT 1

employee2 = Employee.find_by(name: 'Bob')
  DEBUG   Employee Load (92.0ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."name" = 'Bob' LIMIT 1

employee1.manager == employee2.manager
  DEBUG   Employee Load (697.9ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "employees"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 53]]
  DEBUG   Employee Load (504.1ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "employees"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 53]]
 => true
```

I can compare the values of the foreign columns directly, but that's less idiomatic and can be difficult to refactor later on:

```
employee1.manager_id == employee2.manager_id
 => true
```

EDIT: I've added my own answer as a solution to this question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post my own answer for the time being. I've monkey-patched Active Record to include a new method, `compare_association`, which allows you to compare foreign objects on different ActiveRecords without hitting the DB.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def compare_association(association_name, record)
      association = self.class.reflect_on_association(association_name)
      foreign_key = association.foreign_key

      return self.read_attribute(foreign_key) == record.read_attribute(foreign_key)
    end
  end
end
```

Example:

```
# Compare the 'manager' association of `employee1` and `employee2`
# Equivalent to `employee1.manager_id == employee2.manager_id` but without
# referencing the DB columns by name.
employee1.compare_association(:manager, employee2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're going to be needing/using the `Manager` for the `Employee` during the operation, you can make sure you load that object when the employee is loaded, that will prevent the trip back to the database:

```
employee1 = Employee.includes(:manager).find_by(name: 'Alice')
employee2 = Employee.includes(:manager).find_by(name: 'Bob')
employee1.manager == employee2.manager
 => true # database hit not needed...
```

That or just compare the IDs, but make a helper method on Employee like

```
class Employee
  def same_manager?(other_employee)
    other_employee.manager_id == self.manager_id
  end
end
```

At least that way it's given a name and the operation within it makes sense in context.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I should clarify, the database doesn't need to do extra work for this comparison so I'd prefer it didn't. That rules out your first suggestion. The second suggestion is definitely good practice, but I am still looking for a solution that doesn't reference the DB column names (since those could change in the future)